# Normal distribution question about areas

Tags: probability

Suppose we have $\mu = 30$ and $\sigma = 4$ and we know that our random variable is normally distributed.

The problem:

Find $P(30 \leq X \leq 35).$

We get $P(0 \leq Z \leq 1.25)=P\left(\frac{30-30}{4}\leq \frac{X-30}{4}\leq \frac{35-30}4\right)$

where $Z=\frac{X-30}4\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$.

The result is the area under the curve of the pdf of $\mathcal N(0,1)$ left of $1.25$ - the area from $-\infty$ to  $0$. Why is this the case? And more importantly why is the answer $0.8944-0.5$?

I have trouble because the area below $1.25$ is $0.8907$ and  NOT $0.84123$.

Comment: See the table of the distribution function of the standard normal case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table. $\Phi(1.25)=0.89435$. So the right result is $0.89435-0.5=0.39435$.

Answer (score 0):

For any random variable $\xi$ and any two numbers $x<y$,
\begin{align*}
P(x<\xi\le y)
&=P(\{x<\xi\} \cap \{\xi\le y\})\\
&=P(x<\xi)+P(\xi\le y)-P(\{x<\xi\} \cup \{\xi\le y\})\\
&=P(x<\xi)+P(\xi\le y)-1\\
&=P(\xi\le y)-(1-P(x<\xi))\\
&=P(\xi\le y)-P(\xi\le x)
\end{align*}
using the formulas $P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)$, $P(\Omega)=1$ and $P(A)=1-P(A^c)$.

In your example, we have that
$$
P(0\le Z\le1.25)=P(Z\le1.25)-P(Z\le0)=\Phi(1.25)-\Phi(0)\approx0.39435,
$$
where $\Phi$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution.